# akka-http net::err_incomplete_chunked_encoding 200 (ok)

Tags: angularjs, scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to send a large/often slow response to the browser to be rendered into an excel file using Akka-http:
i.e.:

## in ui code

```
$http({
  method : "post",
  url: "myUrl",
  data: "large amount of request data to run a api call",
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then
  (function mySuccess(response) {
    var blob = new Blob([response.data], type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    savesAs(blob, "excel.xlsx")
})
```

The slow api runs and I try to chunk the data back i.e.:

```
path(myPath) {
  post {
    entity(as[MyPredicates]) { entity =>
      val slowApi = Future[List[Results]] = runSlowApi(entity)
      val excel = slowApi.map(data => generateExcel(data)).toByteArray
      val source = Source.fromFuture(excel).map(ByteString.apply)
      val chunkStream = source.via(new Chunker(chunkSize = 8192))
      chunkStream.keepAlive(1.second, () => TextMessage.Strict("ping"))
      complete(HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, chunkStream)
  }
}
```

for anything less than 60 seconds this works fine, however after 60 seconds it always fails with a

> akka-http net::err_incomplete_chunked_encoding 200 (ok)

on the browser.

I've tried `withRequestTimeOut`/`withRequestTimeouResponse`/`withoutSizeLimit` and setting a timeout on the client but nothing works?

Answer (score 0):

It will work better if the code uses `responseType: 'blob'`:

```
$http({
  method : "post",
  url: "myUrl",
  data: "large amount of request data to run a api call",
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  },
  ̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶T̶y̶p̶e̶:̶ ̶'̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶b̶u̶f̶f̶e̶r̶'̶
  responseType: 'blob'
}).then
  (function mySuccess(response) {
    ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶b̶l̶o̶b̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶B̶l̶o̶b̶(̶[̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶]̶,̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶:̶ ̶'̶a̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶/̶v̶n̶d̶.̶o̶p̶e̶n̶x̶m̶l̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶t̶s̶-̶o̶f̶f̶i̶c̶e̶d̶o̶c̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶.̶s̶p̶r̶e̶a̶d̶s̶h̶e̶e̶t̶m̶l̶.̶s̶h̶e̶e̶t̶'̶)̶;̶
    var blob = response.data;
    savesAs(blob, "excel.xlsx")
})
```